# How to have relative mouse position on javascript 2D canvas of online chat where people can move their character with click

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, resize, mouselistener

I am creating a 2D enviroment that acts like chat but with avatars that can move through the canvas.
Users can move their character through the screen clicking on the x axis where they want to move.
My problem is that the mouse position that the client gets and sends to the server is not the same for every user (because of different window sizes), so when the server sends everyone the new position in pixels, is not relative to the size of everyone's screen, because 100 pixels in one users screen who's width is 1080 pixels is not the same than one with a smaller screen (for example of 200 pixels).
How can I get the mouse position relative to the canvas size so every user paints everyone on their relative position of the canvas?

Comment: How are you setting up the canvas size in a client?

Comment: @AHaworth I have the canvas inside a div that measures exactly what I want the canvas to measure. So I have a method resize that is called at the beginning and on every windowResize that uses the parent size and assigns that to canvas.heigth and canva.width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you send the mouse positions not as absolute values but as a % of offset within the canvas width and height - then each site can work out where to put the avatar because it knows the actual dimensions of the canvas for its site.